# get user id in the url after login in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, email

i have one login page in that i have two user_types..one is vendor and another one is user..

So..what i want to do is whenever user or vendor logged in from login..they have to redirect to dashboard..in that i want to get that user_id in the URL..

Here is my login Controller:

public function signin()
    {

```
    $data['error'] ="Invalid Login";
             if($this->input->post())
           {

              $user = $this->LoginModel->login($this->input->post());
              if(count($user)>0)
                {
                       $data = array(
                             'user_id' => $user['user_id'],
                             'first_name' => $user['first_name'],
                             'email' => $user['email'],
                             'password' => $user['password']
                            );

              $this->session->set_userdata($data);



           if($user['user_type_id'] == '1')
          {

                  redirect(base_url('index.php/Login/vendor_dashboard'));

          } 


        elseif($user['user_type_id'] == '2')
         {
              redirect(base_url('index.php/Login/user_dashboard'));
         }

        else
        {
          redirect(base_url('index.php/Login/dashboard'));
        }

         }
     else
     {
         $data["error_message"]="Invalid User Name and Password combination";
     }
}
```

$this->load->view('Admin/login_view',$data);

}

This is my Model:

```
function login($post='')
{
 $this->db->where(array('email' => $post['email'], 'password' => $post['password']));
 $query = $this->db->get('users');

 return $query->row_array();
}
```

Please someone help me..

How to do this..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would do something like this 
**Edit Made**

```
 redirect(base_url('index.php/Login/user_dashboard/'.$this->session->user_id);
```

Comment: so then you can access it using $this->uri->segment(3);   in the function that you are calling

Comment: please note the change i have made i mean its no really necessary but i have chaged the The concatination to get the data from session rather than access the array.......also please accept my answer if it helped

Comment: i have another doubt..in that dashboard user have 3 tabs..when they click on first tab the page will redirect to particular page..in that page also i need to call that user_id..can you please tell me how can i do that..

Comment: Since your user ID is in session you can now concatenate the I'd the same way it was done in the redirect to the anchor tag. Href="link/link/"<?php echo $this->session->userid; ?>

Comment: <span class="info-box-text"><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/index.php/Candidate/vendor_view_candidates/"<?php echo $this->session->userid;?>>Candidates</span>   is this correct way..i didn't get user_id

Comment: Use $this-session->user_id. Or.  $this->session->,user data('user_id')

Comment: @M5533 this is more slightly optimized <span class="info-box-text"><a href="<?php echo base_url()."/index.php/Candidate/vendor_view_candidates/".$this->session->user_id ; ?> >Candidates</span>

Comment: Change ->user_id too                                    ->userdata('user_id')

Comment: You are basically accessing your session variable.

Comment: Check you session variable what is set

Comment: Var_dump($_SESSION)

Comment: array(5) { ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1487847216) ["user_id"]=> string(2) "62" ["first_name"]=> string(9) "prasanna2" ["email"]=> string(29) "bharathi.nalamalapu@gmail.com" ["password"]=> string(5) "admin" }  it's coming like this..

Comment: base_url('index.php/Login/user_dashboard/'.$_SESSION['user_id']);

Comment: Change the controller and function names to your desired ones

Comment: base_url('index.php/change_controller/change_function/'.$_SESSION['user_id']);

Comment: <a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/change_controller/change_function/'.$_SESSION['user_id']); ?>" >

Comment: it's working..here it is  <span class="info-box-text"><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Requirements/vendor_view_requirements/'.$this->session->user_id); ?>" >Requirements</span>

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
redirect(base_url('index.php/Login/vendor_dashboard?user_id='.$user['user_id'])
```

Comment: i have another doubt..in that dashboard user have 3 tabs..when they click on first tab the page will redirect to particular page..in that page also i need to call that user_id..can you please tell me how can i do tha

Answer (score 0):

login post form function

```
public function login()
{
    //fetch form data
     ---------------
    //set session
    this->session->set_userdata('userName', $username);
    $this->session->set_userdata('userId', $userid);
    //redirect 
    $this->user_dashboard();  
}
public function user_dashboard(){
  if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
  $data['usertype']= $_SESSION['userId'];//0=admin,1=vender etc
 }
  if()
   {//}
   else
   {//}
}
```

use

```
<?php redirect(base_url('index.php/user_dashboard'), 'refresh'); ?>
```